# ruby rspec how to mock a method call with an instance variable

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to write a Rspec test for a ruby function which lives in a new file and references an instance variable inside a controller file. I am having unable to mock anything for the line

```
flag = @domain.feature?("BrandNewFeature")
```

When I run the above code I get error on line

```
flag = @domain.feature?("BrandNewFeature")
```

saying

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `feature?' for nil:NilClass>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

play.rb

```
Api.controllers :playbooks do
before do
    @domain = account.domain

def get_filter(param)
    f = find_lists(param)
```

play_help.rb

```
module ApiHelpers
def find_lists(params)
    flag = @domain.feature?("BrandNewFeature")
    folder = ListQueries.folders(params) if flag
    folder
```

play_help_spec.rb

```
require "unit/spec_help"
require_project "api/helpers/play_help.rb"

RSpec.describe ApiHelp do

describe "#find_matching_lists" do
    allow(list_queries).to receive(:folders).and_return(folders)
    binding.pry
    domainDouble = double()
    allow(Domain).to receive(:new).and_return(domainDouble)

    allow(domainDouble).to receive(:feature?).with("BrandNewFeature").and_return(true)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock an instance variable in rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248095/how-can-i-mock-an-instance-variable-in-rspec)

Comment: I don't know what `account` is but it seems like mocking `account.domain` would be better and easier in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot controll the instance that you need to mock then you can use [`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance):

```
RSpec.describe ApiHelp do
  let(:folders) { ... }
  let(:params) { ... }

  before do 
    allow_any_instance_of(Domain)
      .to receive(:feature?).with('BrandNewFeature').and_return(true)
    allow(ListQueries)
      to receive(:folders).with(params).and_return(folders)
  end

  describe '#find_matching_lists' do
    expect(ApiHelp.get_filter).to eq(folders)

    expect_any_instance_of(Domain).to have_received(:feature?).once
    expect(ListQueries).to have_received(folders).once
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried this scenario? Is this working for you? I am still getting an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When I run the test, I see it errors out in play_help.rb. Also in the play_help.rb @domain is coming out Nil (I checked by utting binding.pry)
    => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `feature?' for nil:NilClass>

Comment: What is `@domain` in your helper?